# validation on lookup object

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I have lookup on account of Sell_Request__c object.

I want validation on Sell_Request__c to check if account-status is **Inprogress**
then thrown an error.but i am not able to achieve this as not able to find account> in custom object.Please suggest

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: i was just trying to build a validation on Sell_Request__c ,but from there i am not able to check account.Status

Comment: Presuming I understand your question correctly, you can't do this in a validation rule.

Comment: Your Sell_Request__c will have many Accounts (as a related list).  Validation rule can't handle this.

Comment: got it.means we need to write apex trigger for that.please anyone have any sample code

Comment: Can you please edit your question with clarification. Do you want to check all related accounts status=in progress and throw the error?

Comment: yes.if any of the related account status is InProgress then need to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lookup of Sell_Request__c object on Account, then it makes it one to many relationship between Sell_Request__c and Account. And you want to write a validation rule on parent side by accessing a child field, but there can be many child's i.e. Sell_Request__c can have many Accounts associated with it. Hence, you won't be able to access Account's field from Sell_Request__c object.

Comment: i am not able to get ,how  i can prepare a SOQL query on Sell_Request__c trigger

Comment: Hi Sam, before writing the trigger, you need to understand that there will be many accounts related to Sell_Request__c object, so you will check which account's status ? And for the sample trigger code, please refer [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) trailhead module  and as far as SOQL query is concerned, you can query using the child relationship name in your trigger, you can get help on SOQL from [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) trailhead module

Answer (score 0):

Since you have many related accounts for Sell_Request__c, you need to loop through each account and check its status. If any of the account with status = in progress throw an error. You can use the below trigger to validate on parent side(Sell_Request__c). Please use the correct api name, child relationship name, picklist values as you defined.

```
trigger SellRequestTrigger on Sell_Request__c (after update){
    Map<Id, List<Account>> accountsMap = new Map<Id, List<Account>>();
    for(Sell_Request__c req : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Accounts__r) 
                            FROM Sell_Request__c 
                            WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){
        if(!req.Accounts__r.isEmpty()){
            accountsMap.put(req.Id, new List<Account>(req.Accounts__r));
        }
    }
    for(Sell_Request__c req : Trigger.new){
        if(accountsMap.containsKey(req.Id)){
            for(Account acc :accountsMap.get(req.Id)){
                if(acc.Status__c == 'In Progress'){
                    req.addError('<---Error message--->');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember this will fire only when updating Sell_Request__c. If you insert account with status=in progress it won't throw error. For that you need to validate the same on child level. A separate trigger you can write accordingly on Account object.

Comment: Thanks .but i ran the simple query on Editor and its not working.SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Accounts__r) 
                            FROM Sell_Request__c.....................Error is "Didn't understand relationship 'Accounts__r' in FROM part of query call. "

Comment: You need to use correct child relationship name instead of `Accounts__r`

Comment: You can find child relationship name in lookup field created in Account. https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/how-to-find-child-relationship-name-in-salesforce/